# removing dependancy of a private function inside a public function using Rhino Mocks

Tags: mocking, rhino

I am new to mocking, and have started with Rhino Mocks. My scenario is like this..in my class library i have a public function and inside it i have a private function call, which gets output from a service.I want to remove the private function dependency.

```
public class Employee
    {        
        public virtual string GetFullName(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            string middleName = GetMiddleName();
            return string.Format("{0} {2} {1}", firstName, lastName,middleName );
        }

        private virtual string GetMiddleName()
        {
            // Some call to Service

            return "George";
        }
    }
```

This is not my real scenario though, i just wanted to know how to remove dependency of GetMiddleName() function and i need to return some default value while unit testing.

Note : I won't be able to change the private function here..or include Interface..Keeping the functions as such, is there any way to mock this.Thank

Comment: That code won't compile to start with - a private method can't be virtual.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this part: "a private function call, which gets output from a service". That service should be injected, so that you can mock it out. If it creates a concrete instance of the service itself, then I don't think Rhino can help you.

[TypeMock](http://site.typemock.com/) may be able to help you - I believe that lets you mock out *anything*, but at the cost of being more invasive.

You shouldn't remove the dependency of *calling* the private method, you should remove the dependency *within* that private method. If you can't do that, your code simply isn't testable without something like TypeMock.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use the Extract and Override pattern to derive a testable class from the class under test and override the `private` method (which should be something other than `private` in your example as a `private` method cannot be `virtual` - perhaps you meant `protected`?) to allow you to override the method.

```
public class Employee
{        
    public virtual string GetFullName(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        string middleName = GetMiddleName();
        return string.Format("{0} {2} {1}", firstName, lastName,middleName );
    }

    protected virtual string GetMiddleName()
    {
        // Some call to Service

        return "George";
    }
}

///<summary>
///Testable Employee class
///</summary>
public class TestableEmployee : Employee
{    
    public string MiddleName;

    public virtual string GetFullName(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        string middleName = GetMiddleName();
        return string.Format("{0} {2} {1}", firstName, lastName,middleName );
    }

    protected override string GetMiddleName()
    {
        // provide own implementation to return 
        // property that we can set in the test method

        return MiddleName;
    }
}
```

test method

```
[TestMethod]
public GetFullName_ReturnsSetName()
{
    var testEmployee = new TestableEmployee();
    string firstName = "first";
    string middleName = "middle";
    string lastName = "last";

    TestableEmployee.MiddleName = middleName;

    string fullName = GetFullName(firstName, lastName);

    Assert.AreEqual(string.Format("{0} {2} {1}", 
                    firstName, lastName, middleName ), 
                    fullName
                    );
}
```

if `GetMiddleName()` is wrapper around a service call, then it might be a more testable design to have the service interface as a property of the `Employee` class. This way, you can mock out the service type using the Extract and Override pattern or using an Inversion of Control (IoC) container like [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649080.aspx) or [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/).